# Missing 'Strict-Transport-Security' header in sharepoint web application

Tags: 2013, security, sharepoint-on-prem, iis7

we have SharePoint site deployed on the internet and when we scan some security settings we found below issue

Missing 'Strict-Transport-Security' header
Scanner discovered that the affected application is using HTTPS however does not use the HSTS header.

Answer (score 2):

Have you enabled HTTP Strict Transport Security on the web application? You can run below command to get the status (true mean enabled & false mean not)

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication https://sharepoint.example.com
$wa.HttpStrictTransportSecuritySettings.IsEnabled
```

If it is not enabled then you have to enable it on web application level. run the below powershell for it.

```
 $wa = Get-SPWebApplication https://sharepoint.example.com
$wa.HttpStrictTransportSecuritySettings.IsEnabled = $true
$wa.Update()
```

Read more on this blog: [Enabling HTTP Strict Transport Security for SharePoint Server 2016](https://thesharepointfarm.com/2016/04/enabling-http-strict-transport-security-for-sharepoint-server-2016/)

Comment: if i run this command any impact on web application bcz our web app is in production

Comment: i would 1st check the status of the hsts? is true or false?

Comment: it is not working when i run below command in sharepoint 2013 PS C:\Users\spuseradmin> $wa.HttpStrictTransportSecuritySettings.IsEnabled = $true
The property 'IsEnabled' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the
property exists and can be set.
At line:1 char:1
+ $wa.HttpStrictTransportSecuritySettings.IsEnabled = $true
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound